# Mule splitter, foreach collection using xpath3 expression

Tags: xml, foreach, mule

I have this Mule flow:

```
<file:connector name="input" doc:name="input" autoDelete="false" />
<flow name="flow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="input" path="C:\test" pollingFrequency="100000" />
    <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="prod.xml" />
    <set-variable variableName="tempid" value="150" doc:name="Variable" />
    <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[xpath3('//marketingdetailslist/marketdetails/*', payload, 'NODESET' )]">
        <enricher source="#[flowVars.tempid]" target="#[xpath3('//marketdetails/target')]" >
        <logger message="inside  enricher ~~~~~#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </enricher>
    </foreach>

    <logger message="after enrichment  response~~~~~~.......#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Which receives this XML as input:

```
<marketingdetailslist>
       <marketdetails>
           <Jan>
               <target>100</target>
               <productname>Electronics</productname>               
           </Jan>
           <Feb>
              <target>50</target>
               <productname>Woodenitems</productname>
           </Feb>
       </marketdetails>
</marketingdetailslist>
```

And this would be the expected output, having the values change:

```
<marketingdetailslist>
       <marketdetails>
           <Jan>
               <target>150</target>
               <productname>Electronics</productname>               
           </Jan>
           <Feb>
              <target>150</target>
               <productname>Woodenitems</productname>
           </Feb>
       </marketdetails>
</marketingdetailslist>
```

I can't get the expected output. What would I need to change in my flow to achieve that?

Comment: Did you try `#[xpath3('./target')]`?

Comment: what is #[xpath3('./target')] ?  can you please tell  the flow

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to emulate the [XSL-T Transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XSLT+Transformer) with a set of message processors. You may succeed but it would be much better to use XSL-T instead, as it is designed for performing this kind of transformation.

Comment: my requirement doesn't need  XSL-T Transformer . the above flow needs to be worked with some corrections.

Comment: It's probably possible to load the XML into a DOM an mutate the DOM elements in memory in order to perform the changes you desire procedurally. But that would be akin to recreate XSL-T in a clunky manner... Better use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: but my requirement is like this. anyone shed light what needs to be changed in my flow.